Find values from specific condition
I'd like to retrieve the values in column A for a specific service that don't appear in columns B and C (column B being the service and column C the values similar to column A).
There is the link of my Sheets
I tried a formula found in another post but I can't apply it to my situation.
=FILTER(A2:A;NON(COUNTUNIQUEIFS(C2:C;A2:A;B2:B;"Service 1")))
In the Sheets shared above, you have the expected results for service 1 and service 2 (columns E and F).


You may try:
=filter(A2:A;isna(xmatch(A2:A;filter(C:C;B:B="Service 1"))))


